# Need help sorting arraylist alphabetically

Tags: java, file, arraylist

I need help sorting an array list that contains all the names in the names.txt file. I tried Collections.sort() like suggested but the list is still unsorted. What am I doing wrong?

```
private static void Excerise04(String fname) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner filescanner = new Scanner(new File(fname));
    while (filescanner.hasNext()) {
        String line = filescanner.next();
        ArrayList<String> set = new ArrayList<>();
        set.add(line);
        Collections.sort(set);
        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

I tried adding `Collections.sort(set)` to sort array list alphabetically but nothing happened, it didn't sort, just printed out unsorted list.

Comment: java.text.RuleBasedCollator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare the `List` of lines **outside** the loop in order to collect all the lines together.

```java
List<String> set = new ArrayList<>();
// lines would probably be a better variable name
```

Use `Scanner#nextLine` instead of `Scanner#next` to read the entire line, including whitespace.

```java
String line = filescanner.nextLine();
```

Finally, sort and display the `List` **after** the loop, after you've read everything.

```java
while (filescanner.hasNext()) {
    // ...
}
Collections.sort(set);
System.out.println(set);
```

Comment: This my output. it is still not sorted https://i.imgur.com/KGZkI8Z.png

Comment: @CM138 You're probably not reading the output right since your lines contain commas in them. Use `set.forEach(System.out::println);` to see each line printed on a separate line.